# Как правильно добавить return после каждого метода?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

после вывода ответа на каждую функцию, в консоле пишет none, я так понимаю что это из-за того что я забыл добавить return после каждого метода, подскажите как правильно это сделать?

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, city):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
        self.city = city
        self.login_attempts = 0

    def describe_user(self):
        print("Name: " + self.first_name.title() + 
            "\nLast name: " + self.last_name.title() + 
            "\nAge: " + str(self.age) + 
            "\nCity: " + self.city.title())

    def greet_user(self):
        print("Hello " + self.first_name.title() + " from " + self.city.title())

    def increment_login_attempts(self):
        self.login_attempts += 1
        print("Login attempts: " + str(self.login_attempts))

    def reset_login_attempts(self):
        self.login_attempts = 0
        print("Reset, now login attempts: " + str(self.login_attempts))

class Admin(User):

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, city):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, age, city)
        self.privileges = ('Can add message', 'Can del user', 'Can ban user')

    def show_privileges(self):
        print("Rights admin: " + str(self.privileges))



new_user = User('Kate', 'perry', '35', 'new york')

lisa = User('lisa', 'petrova', '23', 'st.petersburg')

print(new_user.describe_user())

print(new_user.greet_user())

print(new_user.increment_login_attempts())

print(new_user.reset_login_attempts())

Lawliet = Admin('lawliet', 'kriss', '25', 'krasnodar')

Lawliet.show_privileges()
```

Comment: заменить ваш `print` на `return`

Answer (score 2):

Надо определиться - вы хотите, чтобы сама функция выводила описание и т.п. через print, или уже при работе с экземпляром, например print(new_user.describe_user()).

Если первый вариант, то нужно

```
print(new_user.describe_user())
```

Заменить на

```
new_user.describe_user()
```

Если второй вариант, то вместо print в функции давать команду return. Например:

```
def describe_user(self):
    return (
        "Name: "
        + self.first_name.title()
        + "\nLast name: "
        + self.last_name.title()
        + "\nAge: "
        + str(self.age)
        + "\nCity: "
        + self.city.title()
    )
```